# How to avoid creating the GameObject on screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am instantiating enemy(Clones) from an enemy GameObject in Unity using c#. I have written a destroy function to delete only the enemy(Clones) when the bullet hits them. Unity renders the enemy GameObject on screen.

I cannot destroy this GameObject in runtime since unity will not instantiate any more enemy(Clones). Please help me not render the base enemy GameObject as it serves no purpose on screen.

Note: Enemy is scripted to walk towards player position and hence keeping the object outside the screen is pointless.
Please Help

here is a snippet of my code. I dragged the enemy GameObject into the Project section. Now it has created 2 Enemy objects on screen

```
public Rigidbody2D enemy;
void enemySpawn()
{
    Rigidbody2D enemyInstance;
    enemyInstance = Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(Random.Range (2,8), Random.Range (-4,4), 0), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,0))) as Rigidbody2D;   
}
```

Comment: How about an mcve - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "unity will not instantiate any more enemy(Clones)" I am not sure what you are saying. Make your enemy a prefab and Instantiate them from the prefab. That way you don't have to have any enemy on the scene.

Comment: thanks alterfox, will keep this in mind.

"unity will not instantiate any more enemy(Clones)" - if the enemy GameObject is destroyed by the bullet - @Imtiaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your enemy into [prefab](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) this can be done by dragging the gameObject into projectview.

You can instantiate new enemies from the prefabs with any gameObject. For example an empty one without any rendering components.

Instantiate can be done with this kind of script:

```
   public GameObject enemy;
   void InstantiateEnemy () {
      GameObject enemyClone= (GameObject) Instantiate(enemy, transform.position, transform.rotation);
   }
```

Just set the `public GameObject` in the editor and call the `InstantiateEnemy` function from somewhere.

Comment: what do I do with the enemy gameObject in the Hierarchy section, post making a prefab?

Comment: You can remove it. Just make new empty gameObject named for example "EnemySpawn" and attach script containing the code that instantiates prefabs.

Comment: All right I got it. 
I made enemy as a public GameObject and set the same i the editor as you mentioned. Thanks MaZZZu.